# Convert epoch timestamp to human readable

Tags: datetime, date

I am struggling to find out a way to do this simply. (or at all)

Assuming I have the following:

timestamp: 1697513559
timezone: -0500

How can I convert that to human readable format?

Comment: Is this question related to latex?

Comment: Aren't all questions in this stackexchange implied to be related to LaTeX?

Comment: No, it happens that some question here are not related to latex.

Comment: @user606723 You'd be surprised how many no-LaTeX questions get asked. As it is not really evident from your question, I thought I'd ask...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using PGFCalendar we can convert any *duration after point in time* into a date. We just need to handle the timezone first by manipulating minutes and hours and adjust the *duration after point in time* accordingly.

This uses the PGFInt module that gets loaded by PGFCalendar but is otherwise undocumented. (It's basically a clone from l3int.)

Besides the scratch count `\count@` no other temporary macro is used. This only handles positive epoch values properly and the timezone must be four digits for nonegative values or a minus and four digits for negative values. (The parser is relatively dumb.)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\epochtodate[8]{%
  \pgfintset\count@{\pgfintmod{#1}{86400}}%         time
  \edef#6{\pgfintdivtruncate{\count@}{3600}}%       hour
  \edef#7{\pgfintdivtruncate{\count@-#6*3600}{60}}% minute
  \edef#8{\pgfinteval{\count@-#6*3600-#7*60}}%      second
  \pgfintset\count@  {#6\ifnum#2<0 \epochtodate@TZhour  #2\else\epochtodate@TZhour  +#2\fi}%
  \edef#7{\pgfinteval{#7\ifnum#2<0 \epochtodate@TZminute#2\else\epochtodate@TZminute+#2\fi}}%
  \epochtodate@check{\count@}{#7}{60}%              check timezoned minutes
  \edef#6{\the\count@}%                             hours
  \pgfintset\count@{\pgfintdivtruncate{#1}{86400}}% days
  \epochtodate@check{\count@}{#6}{24}%              check timezoned hours
  \epochtodate@zerofill{#6}\epochtodate@zerofill{#7}\epochtodate@zerofill{#8}%
  \pgfcalendardatetojulian{1970-01-01+\count@}{\count@}%
  \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\count@}{#3}{#4}{#5}}
\newcommand*\epochtodate@TZhour  [5]{#1#2#3}
\newcommand*\epochtodate@TZminute[5]{#1#4#5}
\newcommand*\epochtodate@zerofill[1]{\edef#1{\ifnum#1<10 0\fi#1}}%
\newcommand*\epochtodate@check[3]{%
  \ifnum#2<0
    \pgfintset#1{#1-1}%
    \edef#2{\pgfinteval{#2+#3}}%
  \else
    \unless\ifnum#2<#3\relax
      \pgfintset#1{#1+1}%
      \edef#2{\pgfinteval{#2-#3}}%
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\epochtodate{1697513559}{-0500}{\Year}{\Month}{\Date}{\Hour}{\Minute}{\Second}
Epoch 1697513559 in TZ -0500 is \Year-\Month-\Date\ \Hour:\Minute:\Second

\epochtodate{2147483647}{0000}{\Year}{\Month}{\Date}{\Hour}{\Minute}{\Second}
Epoch 2147483647 in TZ 0000 is \Year-\Month-\Date\ \Hour:\Minute:\Second
\end{document}
```

### Output

> Epoch 1697513559 in TZ -0500 is 2023-10-16 22:32:39
> Epoch 2147483647 in TZ 0000 is 2038-01-19 03:14:07

Comment: I was going to do a calculated version before I decided to cheat and use `os.date` but don't you have to worry about leap seconds? (although you got the same seconds field as me so perhaps not?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle According to a [reliable source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time): “Each leap second uses the timestamp of a second that immediately precedes or follows it.” So, leap seconds are ignored. That means Unix time doesn't truly measure the seconds after 1970-01-01. If someone truly wants to mess with timezones and leap seconds … well, good luck!

Comment: ah, thanks.......

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel

`\newcommand{\epoch}{1697513559}`
`\newcommand{\tz}{-0500}`

`\epochtodate{\epoch}{\tz}{\Year}{\Month}{\Date}{\Hour}{\Minute}{\Second}`
`\typeout{Epoch 1697513559 in TZ -0500 is \Year-\Month-\Date\ \Hour:\Minute:\Second}`

Any idea why this is screwing up? Outputting: Epoch 1697513559 in TZ -0500 is 2023-10-16\ 0-474:0-908:39

Comment: @user606723 Expansion issue. Quick fix would be `\expanded{\noexpand\epochtodate{\epoch}{\tz}}{\Year}` and so on.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use lualatex then Lua's date functions are available so

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\directlua{tex.print(os.date("\@percentchar c" ,1697513559))}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

Comment: Well, that's too easy … (You're missing a `\makeatother`.) This seems to take the machine's timezone (BST) in consideration.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel well not strictly missing, just not used:-) But I could add one. On the time zone, I suppose I could use `%t` and get a table back of all the fields and manage the time zone handling, but a one line answer seemed more suitable for the  brevity of the question.